# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "iptoc" does not exist

Tags: python, django

I have seen all of the similarly titled questions. Case is different:

The problem arises when running the unittest.

I had to import some foreign tables because they already had data in them (country region city ) data. So I had to create the Model as managed = false

```
class Iptoc(models.Model):
    id_ip = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ip_from = models.IntegerField()
    ip_to = models.IntegerField()
    country_code2 = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    threecode = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'iptoc'
```

When I do a query in a view it works 100% correct that is, it does use the table.

```
def index_country(request):
    # getting the hostname by socket.gethostname() method
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    ## getting the IP address using socket.gethostbyname() method
    ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    ## printing the hostname and ip_address
    print(f"Hostname: {hostname}")
    print(f"IP Address: {ip_address}")
    x = 18874378
    record = Iptoc.objects.get(ip_to__gte=x,ip_from__lte=x)
    pais = record.country_name
    print(pais)
```

The table in my postgresql is called iptoc (no capital letters)

When I run this test:

```
class HomeTests(TestCase):
    def test_home_view_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('country')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

I get:

```
  File "/home/alvar/PycharmProjects/Carpeta9Abril/venv9Abril/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "iptoc" does not exist
LINE 1: ... "iptoc"."threecode", "iptoc"."country_name" FROM "iptoc" WH...
```

Comment: For tests, it works with a database with a `_test` suffix, so if your database is named `foo`, it will use `foo_test` for tests, so that needs to create such table as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tests, it works with a database with a `_test` suffix, so if your database is named *`foo`*, it will use `foo_test` for tests.

You thus should create an equivalent table in the test database.